# WooCommerce Product Filter не работает кнопка(ajax)?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, vps

Добрый день!
На моем сайте стоит плагин WooCommerce Product Filter, основная особенность его - это создание расширенных фильтров. В панели управления этого плагина помимо множества кнопок есть 2 кнопки - "Add advanced Filter" и "Range filter".
При нажатии на "Range filter" всё прекрасно работает(появляется блок под кнопкой), но "Add advanced filter" не работает никак, хотя в инспекторе на этот запрос стоит Status 200 OK.
Развернул полную копию(бд+сайт) на локалке, там же все работает без нареканий.
В чем может быть проблема?
Мой сайт размещен на VPS. 
Спасибо за внимание:)

Comment: Извиняюсь, за поздний ответ - но вдруг кому-нибудь понадобится.
Вся проблема была в AdBlock, он блокировал почему-то контент кнопки Advanced filter:)